# Connecting to production node when short name is set

Tags: debugging, erlang, elixir, remote-debugging, epmd

I am running an Elixir app on my 3 servers. I recently needed to connect nodes so that I can sync something between them, and for that I set short names for each node.

I am using Edeliver/Distillery to generate release and deploy. I copied `var/vm.args` to release directory on each node and changed `-name blah@ip` to `-sname name@nodename`. Nodes can see and connect to each other without problem.

Before I given each node a name, I used ssh to remotely connect to my nodes when I needed to debug my app. I used this approach:

- `ssh node -L 4369:127.0.0.1:4369`
- run `epmd -names` on my local machine to find out port of my app
- kill last ssh and run `ssh node -L 4369:127.0.0.1:4369 -L port:127.0.0.1:port` to have access to running node on my machine
- run `iex --hidden --erl '-name debug -setcookie cookie_like_server'` on my machine
- now I had access to remote node, e.g. I could use `observer` to see my remote node

The same procedure won't work now.

First I see an error saying nodes using short and long names cannot connect to each other, obviously.

I changed my `iex` command to `iex --hidden --erl '-sname debug -setcookie cookie_like_server'` to use short name. This way connection times out when I try to connect to remote node on `observer`.

I don't really get the problem. Am I doing something wrong? Is here another way to get access to a running node that uses short name?

BTW, I used ssh so that my traffic will be encrypted. Please do tell me if there is a solution that makes my connection non-encrypted, though I will probably not use it, or somehow tunnel it through ssh.

**UPDATE**

I tried method suggested by @christophe-de-troyer. TLDR, didn't work.

```
vahid@arch-adtube ~/ % iex --sname debug --cookie 'cookie' --remsh backend-platform@prod-1
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.0.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Could not contact remote node backend-platform@prod-1, reason: :nodedown. Aborting...
```

`ssh prod-1 -L 4369:127.0.0.1:4369` was running, and `epmd -names` reports `backend-platform` as a running node correctly.

Comment: I think `peerage` will help you.

Comment: How can `peerage` can help me? It says it is used to connect nodes on a cluster. I already have that. I want to connect a shell from my system to a production node to debug and monitor it sometimes. @JiangYD

Comment: Can you provide the /etc/hosts file for both machines you are trying to connect to?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to connect to a remote node you will have to pass a full name (`--name`) instead of a short name (`--sname`), from my experience.

So on Node A, with ip 192.168.1.10, you run:

`iex --name bob@192.168.1.10 --cookie secret`

On node B, with ip 192.168.1.11, you run:

`iex --name alice@192.168.1.11 --cookie secret`

And then on your computer, with ip 192.168.1.12, you can attach to these remote shells using. First of all you have to make sure that your local EPMD port (4369) is bound to the remote server's EPMD port, by tunneling it over SSH.

`ssh a -L 4369:127.0.0.1:4369`

Then you can connect with a remote shell to these nodes using:

`iex --name carol@192.168.1.12 --cookie secret --remsh alice@192.168.1.11`

I have experimented a bit on my machines, and I found out that it only works with IP addresses. My machine running at `machine.example.com`, with hostname `machine`, was not connectable if the name on the remote machine was not qualified with its ip address, or domain name. And I had to match that with the DNS name, or ip address on my connecting client.

There is some interesting traffic on the mailing list of Erlang about this[1].

[1] http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2006-December/024270.html

## Edit

I did some further experimentation and succeeded in connecting to remote nodes with shortnames.

As you already mentioned, you indeed need the two nodes to be running in the same naming mode (i.e., both short, or both fully qualified).

On node `A`, with ip `12.12.12.12`, and FQDN `a.example.com`, I spawned a shell as such:

`iex --sname bob --cookie secret`

On my local machine `L`, with ip `5.5.5.5`, and FQDN `l.notanexample.com`, I spawned a shell as such:

`ssh a -L 4369:127.0.0.1:4369`

`iex --sname alice --cookie secret --remsh bob@a`

The reason this works, and did not before, was because on my local machine, in the `/etc/hosts` file, I did not put a line that bound the hostname (short hostname) to the remote IP.

So in `/etc/hosts` on my local machine I have the following line now:

`12.12.12.12 a`.

Comment: You did not use short names in your *EDIT*, did you mean `--sname`?

Comment: Ah yes,.that is indeed a typo.

Comment: Five years later this post is the only source I could find that explains how to connect to a remote sname node. Thank you!